# Relativpronomen und relativsatz

Tags: relative-clause

Das ist die Frau, ***der*** ich die Wohnung gezeigt habe

Warum wird in diesem Beispiel der Dativ verwendet?

zeigen + dativ ??

Comment: Ja, im Wörterbuch liest Du: jemandem etwas zeigen. Was ist Deine Frage?

Answer (score 1):

Zeigen ist ja, dass Person A Person B darauf hinweist, was zu sehen ist.
Hier geht es also nicht darum, was gezeigt wurde (Akkusativ), sondern wer darauf hingewiesen wurde, was zu sehen ist (Dativ).

Comment: Kurz gesagt: "Ich habe **ihr** (nicht 'sie') die Wohnung gezeigt." -> "... **der** ich die Wohnung gezeigt habe."

Comment: aka "wem ich etwas gezeigt habe" ;-)